# Passing keyword argument to quad integration functions in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, keyword-argument

I want to pass keyword arguments to integrand function in the dblquad or nquad. 
Is it possible at all to have a keyword argument here or should I just opt in for having positional arguments only?

Basically, I tried to pass dictionary as a normal argument. Below is my attempt at doing that:

```
def foo(A, B, **kwargs):
    alpha = kwargs.get('alpha', 1.0)
    beta = kwargs.get('beta', 1.0)
    return A*alpha+B*beta
def integrator(**kwargs):
    alpha = kwargs.get('alpha', 1.0)
    beta = kwargs.get('beta', 1.0)
    a = dblquad(foo, 0, 2*pi, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*pi, args=(kwargs))
integrator(alpha = 1.0, beta = 2.0)
```

Python complains about having an improper number of positional arguments. It treats keywords dictionary as a number of positional arguments.

Comment: `args` argument is supposed to be a tuple. You may be missing a comma

Comment: @hpaulj I do miss a comma here in the example code, but with a comma, the problem is still there.

Comment: The `args` variables are passed as positionals, e.g  (A, B, kwargs)

Comment: In other `scipy` code I've seen function calls like `fun((iteration_var,)+args)`.  That is, it uses tuple concatenation to combine the iteration variable(s) with the `args` tuple.  So `foo(A, B, alpha, beta)` and `args=(alpha, beta)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: kwargs are not supported.

Possible workarounds include passing keyword args as positionals, passing a single dict as a positional argument, or attaching relevant keywords as attributes to the function you're integrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem just now by passing a function object to the integrate method (my example uses `RK45` instead of quadrature).

Basically, you create a class like this one:

```
class MyFunction(object):
  def __init__(self, constant1, constant2, **kwargs):
    self.constant1 = constant1
    # ... and so on ...

  def __call__(self, t, y):
    # This is your 'fun' that gets passed.
```

When you setup the integrator, you do it like so:

```
my_fun = MyFunction(c1, c2, other_arg = 'foo', bar = 10.0)
integ = RK45(my_fun, t0, y0, tf)
while integ.t < tf and integ.status != 'failed':
  integ.step()
```

This does not, of course, allow you to change the parameters to my_fun in the middle of an integration. But it does allow you to pass a more customizable function to the integration method.